# Type error : Expression has to be an lvalue

Tags: solidity, remix, nft, private-blockchain

I have made a smart contract for nft minting where there is a small part . while compiling I am getting this error .

here is the part where the error is

```
    /**
     * @dev Initializes the contract by setting a `name` and a `symbol` to the token collection.
     */
    constructor (string memory name_, string memory symbol_) {
        name = name;
        symbol = symbol;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
constructor (string memory name_, string memory symbol_) { 
  name = name;
  symbol = symbol; 
}
```

You're assigning `name` and `symbol` to themselves. Here is your error:

```
name = name;
symbol = symbol;
```

As you can see `name` is equal to itself.

You can fix it by assigning the variable properly by using `name_` and `symbol_`:

```
name = name_; 
symbol = symbol_;
```